# PHP Multiply currency variable with decimal

Tags: php

I'm trying to multiply a variable by a decimal (percentage) but it's outputting 0 as the value. The variable has a dollar sign and two decimal places ($53,900.00).

```
$baseprice = $53,900.00;
$ott = .92;
echo ($baseprice * $ott);
```

I think the currency sign ($) is messing it up. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the money_format() function to print it out with the dollar sign and comma. But when you declare a variable as a number it can't contain commas ',' or '$' or it gets cast to a string. Here is an example of using money_format.

```
$baseprice = 53900.00;
$ott = .92;
echo money_format('%n',($baseprice * $ott)); # prints $49,588.00
```

Comment: Ahhh... makes sense. I'm still learning PHP. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you'll also need to remove the comma

```
$baseprice = str_replace(array('$',','), '', $baseprice);
```